# Rounded Corners of a label is not visible

Tags: ios, uilabel, quartz-core

I have two adjacent labels with a separated borders between them. The 1st label should have rounded border only in top-left and bottom-left corners and 2nd label vice versa. For that I used bezierPathWithRoundedRect of UIBezierPath to draw path and set to mask of layer of label. Here is the code :

```
_serverLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
_cpuUsageLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
_serverLabel.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
_serverLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
_serverLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.serverLabel.bounds byRoundingCorners: (UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)].CGPath;    
_serverLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer;

maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.cpuUsageLabel.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){10.0, 10.0}].CGPath;
_cpuUsageLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

I have did these modifications in layoutSubviews of my customized tableViewCell class. It is rounded properly but the rounded edges alone is not visible. Borders in other sides and edges are visible (in black color ). thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this using CALayers and masks

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
label.layer.mask = maskLayer;
where maskPath is a UIBezierPath set up using bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii

Comment: Yeah but there is no problem in the way I did. I gave a background color to label and set background color of label and checked. It getting rounded correctly but the rounded corners alone is not having a border color. I dont understand why. It would be helpful if I know why. I tried setting borderColor of label.layer again. But still it was not changing

Comment: what about drawing a new border  
down vote
accepted
You can set label's border via its underlying CALayer property:

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

myLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;

Comment: I already added those lines and checked. Its not working but. Without setting borderWidth the borders wont be visible.

Comment: Nope.. But I am using in my project. You can check later and tell me. thanks..

Comment: Yeah sure,I will let you know the answer after sometime ryt now iam middle of something else

Comment: k thanks. I will try with some other way and will let you know once I find the solution.

Comment: ok. good.are u malayali?